# Separate key and value pairs into two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, key

What would be the best way to go about separating the key and values into two different arrays so that this -

```
var data = {"A Key": 34, "Another Key": 16, "Last Key": 10};
```

Would become this -

```
data1 = ["A Key", "Another Key", "Last Key"];
data2 = [34, 16, 10];
```

Thanks.

Comment: What about this?

`var data = {"A Key": 34, "Another Key": 16, "Last Key": 10};  
var data1 = Object.keys(data);  
var data2 = Object.values(data);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var data = {"A Key": 34, "Another Key": 16, "Last Key": 10};

var data1 = [],
    data2 = [];

for (var property in data) {

   if ( ! data.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      continue;
   }

   data1.push(property);
   data2.push(data[property]);

}
```

1. Set up two different blank arrays.
2. Iterate through the enumerable properties of the object.
3. If `data` does not have this property explicitly (i.e. not higher up the prototype chain), skip this iteration.
4. Push the key and its value to their respective arrays.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/LYpMx/).

Answer (score 2):

This function will split the `data` object into a keys and a values array. It returns an object, containing both arrays.

```
function splitObj(data){
  var keys = [],
      vals = [];
  for (var l in data) {
   if (data.hasOwnProperty(l){
    keys.push(l);
    vals.push(data[l]];
   }
  }
  return {keys: keys,vals:vals};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data1=[];
data2=[]
for (x in data) {
   data1.push(x);
   data2.push(data[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the properties with a `for in` loop, and then just assign them to arrays as needed.

Make sure you check whether the key is a property of the object, and not of the prototype.

```
var data1 = [];
var data2 = [];

for (var key in p) {
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    data1.push(key);
    data2.push(p[key]);
  }
}
```