# Separating key value pairs into two variables with for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

**edit: don't do this. this was a stupid way of doing something I tried when I was new to programming**

I have a list of 32 pieces of data in an array that are paired like this

```
"foo:bar","baz:example","cat:dog"
```

and I want to loop through that array to and stop on the pair that matches the user's input. So, for example, if the user types in "foo" it'll return both "foo" and "bar" separately, and if the user types in "bar" it'll return both "foo" and "bar". There are no values that repeat.

Right now what I have is a huge table with `if` statements. So `if` the user's input is *x*, then it returns the correct value. I had to do the matching by hand, and I'm assuming that looping through the array until the correct value is found would be more efficient than 64 different `if`s.

I've tried something like this (just an example) using **two** separate arrays:

```
for (var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    if (array[i] === user_input) {
        var index = indexOf(array[i]);
    break;
    }
}
```

and then using the `index` variable as the index number of the value in each array, but it returns `undefined`

I've also tried this: [Separate key and value pairs into two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647944/separate-key-and-value-pairs-into-two-arrays)

But it gives me *all* the values in the array, which I don't want. I just want one specific value that the user inputs. And while I *can* select one specific portion of the array using the index number, I can't figure out how to make that dynamic (e.g. changing based on what the user inputs).

Is it even possible to do this? And if not, what would be the best way?

Thanks.

Comment: `cat,dog` or `cat:dog`?

Comment: @AmitJoki `cat:dog`. Sorry, was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
function getPair(arr, search) {
    var rtn = arr.filter(function (v, i) {
        return new RegExp("\\b" + search + "\\b").test(v);
    })[0];
    return rtn ? rtn.split(':') : -1;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var array = ["foo:bar","baz:example","cat:dog"];
getPair(array, "foo"); //  ["foo","bar"]
```

**Note:** The above function returns `-1` if the search string isn't found in the array.

Comment: Still around 10%, so I would stay away from the functional stuff for a few more years. +1, since I don't see this very often yet.

Comment: what do you not see often? IE countdown?

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you both Amit Joki and @MartinKonecny you both gave me great answers to a stupid question!

Comment: @eric_lagergren, glad to have helped you, and IMO, it wasn't a stupid question

Comment: Note that getPair(array,"f") will also return ["foo","bar"]. getPair(array, "ample") will return ["baz","example"]

Comment: @Christophe, now it wont

Comment: Unfortunately it still does, @AmitJoki see http://jsfiddle.net/Dkg68/2/ Using RegExp("\\B" ...) will return getPair(array, "f") as -1, but if you have the value of "foofoo:barbar" it'll return "foofoo:barbar" instead of -1.

Comment: @eric_lagergren, glad to have helped you again `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that iterates over the array, and checks if the `user_input` is anywhere. If so, it will return the string that it found a match for.

```
function getPair(array, user_input) {
  for (var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
      var pair = array[i].split(':');
      if (pair.indexOf(user_input) >= 0) {
          return pair;
      }
  }
  return [];
}

var array = ["foo:bar","baz:example","cat:dog"];
getPair(array, "foo"); //will return ['foo', 'bar']
getPair(array, "bar"); //will return ['foo', 'bar']
getPair(array, "dog"); //will return ['cat', 'dog']
getPair(array, "zzz"); //will return []
```

Comment: Hmmm... my intent is to have the two values separate so a search for "foo" will return "foo" and "bar" separately. Would `getPair(array, "foo").split(":");` and then assigning [0] and [1] as separate variables be too unweidly? I need to perform math on both of the values.

Comment: @eric_lagergren, something like in my answer?

Comment: No split is a perfect use for this. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to work with objects. First, convert your array:

```
var pair,obj1={},obj2={};
for (var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
  pair=array[i].split(":");
  obj1[pair[0]]=pair[1];
  obj2[pair[1]]=pair[0];
}
```

This will give you the following objects:

```
obj1={
  "foo":"bar",
  "baz":"example",
  "cat":"dog"
};
obj2={
  "bar":"foo",
  "example":"baz",
  "dog":"cat"
};
```

Then based on the user input:

```
if (obj1[user_input]) {return [user_input,obj1[user_input]];}
else if (obj2[user_input]) {return [obj2[user_input],user_input];}
else return undefined;
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x23qG/

Comment: Just noticed your reply, sorry. Is there a reason an object would work better than an array? I'm new to JavaScript, and from what I see here: http://jsperf.com/array-vs-object-performance an array is faster.

Comment: @eric_lagergren in my answer, just look at the expression to retrieve the value, you can't beat that!

Comment: Actually it is incredibly simple, but won't an object just give me the second part of the 'pair'? So obj["foo"] returns "bar" because, at least for my scenario, I need both parts.

Comment: @eric_lagergren in terms of performance, this answer will be better than the accepted answer. But if you look at the test, you'll see that we are talking about extremely short operations! So no significant difference in practice.

Comment: If the user input is "foo", you already have the first part, right :-)

Comment: oh. You're right! But that doesn't allow for the user to search for "bar". See: http://jsfiddle.net/MtXEB/ for what I mean.

Comment: doh! You're right, I missed that part in the question. I will delete my answer.

Comment: Just edit it! I frequent stackoverflow and I love seeing things like yours. It helps me learn and gives me new ideas.