# Angular 2, split data from Json

Tags: json, angular

Hi I have a json from http request, the server json response is this:

```
{
  "map": {
    "03/04": 13,
    "05/04": 41,
    "06/04": 1,
    "12/04": 4,
    "14/04": 7,
    "18/04": 8,
    "19/04": 2,
    "22/04": 1,
    "25/04": 4
  },
  "links": []
}
```

I want to split dates in 1 array and values in other array,
At the end I want :
Data[03/04,05/04,06/04....] and
Val[13,41,1....]
is it possible without difficult implementation?

Comment: Since it's not an array you can use Object.keys() to get your keys and values.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647944/separate-key-and-value-pairs-into-two-arrays

Comment: but what is the keys in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be an approach:

```
   private Data = [];
   private Val = [];
   for (let key in data) {
      this.Data.push(key);
      this.Val.push(data[key])
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
  var a=`{
          "map": {
            "03/04": 13,
            "05/04": 41,
            "06/04": 1,
            "12/04": 4,
            "14/04": 7,
            "18/04": 8,
            "19/04": 2,
            "22/04": 1,
            "25/04": 4
          },
          "links": []
        }`

        var Data=[];
        var val=[]
        for(each in a.map){
            Data.push(each);
            val.push(a.map[each]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let date = Object.keys(JsonRespond.map) // get all keys in map object
let value = [];
date.forEach((key) => {
   value.push(JsonRespond.map[key]);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Object.entries

```
var dates = [];
 var values = [];
 var data = Object.entries(yourObj.map);
 for (var i in data.length) {
     dates.push(data[i][0]);
     values.push(data[i][1]);

 }
```